# How do I change these forms into ajax forms rails

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, ruby-on-rails-3.2

So I have the following forms partials that allow a user to add a value to a table.  I am very new to working with ajax and javascript so I am not entirely sure how to go about this.  However, once the value is entered and submitted, I would like to be able to display the value that has been entered.  Currently, I have to reload the page for that to occur.  I have both a html partial and a mobile partial for use with jquery mobile.

```
#_form.html.erb

<% if @workoutexercises[n].exercise_weight.nil? %>
  <%= form_for @workoutexercises[n], :remote => true do |f| %>
    <div class="input-append"><%= f.text_field :exercise_weight, :class => 'submittable input-small' %>
    <%= button_tag(type: 'submit', class: "btn btn-primary", disable_with: 'Processing...') do %>
      <i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i>
    <% end %></div>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  <%= @workoutexercises[n].exercise_weight %>
<% end %>

#_form.mobile.erb

<% if @workoutexercises[n].exercise_weight.nil? %>
  <%= form_for @workoutexercises[n], :remote => true do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :exercise_weight %>
    <div class="ui-grid-a">
      <div class="ui-block-a"><%= f.text_field :exercise_weight, :class => 'submittable' %></div>
      <div class="ui-block-b"><%= f.submit "Update", "data-role" => "button", "data-theme" => "b" %></div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  </n>
  Weight: <%= @workoutexercises[n].exercise_weight %>
<% end %>
```

I am using the following currently for the submittable javascript.

```
#application.js

$('.submittable').live('change', function() {
  $(this).parents('form:first').submit();
});
```

Thank in advance for any tips or leads in the right direction! Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the appropriate action in your workoutexercises controller, add a new line in your respond_to block to allow a javascript response, as follows:

```
respond_to do |format|
   format.html { redirect_to workoutexercises_url }
   format.js // add this line here
end
```

Then create a new js view template, called for example "update.js.erb" (if the form submits to the update action). Also create a new partial in the same directory, which you could call _show.html.erb.

In the update.js.erb file, you will want to have something like this:

```
// Render the newly created workout into your table
$('#someTableCell').html("<%= j render ("show") %>");
```

This will render a partial (_show.html.erb) containing your newly updated exercises into the table on your page via ajax.

There's no need for the javascript you have at the end of your question if you are using unobtrusive javascript (i.e. using remote => true in your form header).

Comment: Thanks for the response mate, it has provided a lot of clarity as to how to utilize Unobtrusive Javascript.  However I am now running into two more issues.  The first being the I am receiving this error: `ActionView::Template::Error (The partial name () is not a valid Ruby identifier; make sure your partial name starts with a letter or underscore, and is followed by any combinations of letters, numbers, or underscores.)`

Comment: See my edits above. j is shorthand for the escape_javascript method (I had initially put this in the wrong position after render). Also, for your comment about having the wrong id being passed in on update, I would look into nested model forms. See Ryan Bates' screencast about that here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised?view=comments.

Comment: you are probably using the wrong path helper on redirect from your update action. run rake routes in terminal for available paths. it should probably be workout_workoutexercises path and of the form workouts/:id/workoutexercises/:id.

Comment: Everything is working in the correct manner now. It is much appreciated! Thanks You. Cheers.